# Problems regarding Rational numbers

Tags: number-theory

Prove that any rational number $\frac u v$
where $u, v \in \Bbb{Z}$ with $v \ne 0$ may be written as $\frac r s$
where $r$ and $s$ are co-prime integers with $s > 0$.

I can't get $s$ to be only positive

Comment: It says, "**may** be written... with $s>0$".  Can you think of a way to write $2/(-3)$ with a positive denominator?

Comment: take the negative sign to the numerator, or use absolute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove the claim for the case both $u,v > 0$. Let $m = \text{gcd}(u,v)$, then we can write: $u = mr, v = ms$. Thus $\dfrac{u}{v} = \dfrac{mr}{ms} = \dfrac{r}{s}$. Next we show $\text{gcd}(r,s) = 1$. For if $\text{gcd}(r,s) = k > 1$.Then $k \mid r, k \mid s$. Hence $r = pk, s = qk$. So $u = mr = mpk, v = ms = mqk$. Thus $mk \mid u, mk \mid v \implies mk \mid \text{gcd}(u,v) = m\implies k = 1$, contradiction. Thus $\text{gcd}(r,s) = 1$, and this means $r,s$ are co-prime.

Comment: thank you. but why is it enough to prove the claim for u,v >0 ?

Comment: If either one is negative, you can rewrite the ratio as $-\dfrac{u'}{v'}$ where both $u',v'$ are positive.